# Programmatically add layout from number of files

Tags: java, android, file, android-linearlayout

I have the following XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@layout/bginset3" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="false"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp" >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/forfileicon" >
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@android:color/white" >
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imgFileIcon"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                    android:background="@drawable/forfileicon" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvFN"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:textColor="#00A21E"
                    android:textSize="14dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="25dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgFileIcon" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvMD"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:textColor="#00A21E"
                    android:textSize="14dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="25dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/tvFN"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgFileIcon" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And the following Java code:

```
package com.test.testing;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.Date;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.text.format.DateFormat;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class PreviousTrip extends Fragment {
    int i;
    String k = "";

    @Override
    public View onCreateView( LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
        final RelativeLayout mFrame3 =  (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate( R.layout.ptrip, container, false );

        File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/tc/");
        File[] filelist = folder.listFiles();
        String[] theNamesOfFiles = new String[filelist.length];
        if (filelist.length > 0) {
            for (i = 0; i < theNamesOfFiles.length; i++) {
                long lastTime = filelist[i].lastModified();
                String dateString = DateFormat.format("MM/dd/yyyy", new Date(lastTime)).toString();
                theNamesOfFiles[i] = filelist[i].getName();
                k = k + String.valueOf(theNamesOfFiles[i]) + " " + dateString + "\n";
            }
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), k, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "no files", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        return mFrame3;
    }
}
```

What I would like to do is using Java and depending on how many files is in the folder, I would like to use `tvFN` as the filename and `tvMD` as the file modified date. My Java code is able to retrieve the file name and the modified date but how do I modify my script so it adds each `<linearlayout></linearlayout>` automatically depending on the `files.length();` something like this if the folder had three files:

[image]

Comment: Have you considered using `ListView`??

Comment: I looked at it in Eclipse, but wasn't too sure how to implement what I am looking to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend you use a [ListView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html), instead of doing that layout stuff manually. You can then implement an Adapter providing the list, and specify individual list elements (using xml layouts).

Advantage is that you don't have to write everything from scratch, the ListView can even recycle old views when the user switches folders, etc. -> more responsive UI.

To make things even more simple: let your activity/fragment extend [ListActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html)/[ListFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html) and give the ListView the id `@android:id/list`. You also do not need the ScrollView when using an ListView, the ListView scrolls by itself. See the articles linked for a simple example.

Comment: I am not too familiar with ListView, so if you can provide some help I would really appreciate it.

Comment: There's also [ListFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html), sorry I thought of an Activity ;)

Comment: If you run into issues let me know, but I think the examples in the ListFragment and ListActivity articles are quite good, and I'd probably just copy them.

Comment: Starting point: change your layout to a Layout only containing a ListView with the id/list id. Then change your code to use the ListFragment class. Use setListAdapter instead of whatever you currently use. For testing, use an [ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html), for example like in [this tutorial](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=1516). Then, change to your own layout with your own ids.

Comment: I am using ArrayAdapter. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I **strongly** recommend using `ListView` but if you insist then this is how its done:

Your main layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<ScrollView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="false"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp" >

</ScrollView>
```

and then in some other layout file, lets call it row.xml:

```
<LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:id="@+id/row"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/forfileicon" >
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/white" >
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgFileIcon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:background="@drawable/forfileicon" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvFN"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=""
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:textColor="#00A21E"
                android:textSize="14dp"
                android:paddingLeft="25dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgFileIcon" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvMD"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=""
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:textColor="#00A21E"
                android:textSize="14dp"
                android:paddingLeft="25dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tvFN"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgFileIcon" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Then at runtime:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
// apply data on row
((ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scrollView1).addView(view);
```

Comment: Where is `context` used from?

Comment: I would LOVE to use `ListView` as per your recommendation, if I only knew how to accomplish what I am looking to do :)

Comment: if you are in `Activity` then just use `this` like this: `LayoutInflater.from(this);`. But **STOP** right there before its too late, and shift to `ListView`. Please please for your user's sake.

Comment: There are lot of tutorials available online, let me share few links wait.

Comment: `public class PreviousTrip extends Fragment {` should be `public class PreviousTrip extends ListFragment {`

Comment: It seems like the example is Extending `Activity` So can I still use `Fragment`?

Comment: yes you can... Please have a look at tutorial and master `ListView` first, `ListView` can be used in `Fragment`, `Activity`, `ListFragment`, `ListActivty`... anywhere. Once you cross this learning curve you will know.